# What is the difference between these package cache clearing methods?

Tags: apt, package-management

When building Docker images using ubuntu, some devs recommend removing package caches to reduce the size of the generated image by running the following command:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

However, there is also the command `apt-get clean` which removes the package cache located at `/var/cache/apt/archives` (reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto)

Why do devs recommend the former command over the latter? Is there anything to gain by running both commands since they target different cache locations?

Comment: @user535733, sure, here are some https://gist.github.com/marvell/7c812736565928e602c4#gistcomment-2965615  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990329/dockerfile-benefits-of-repeated-apt-cache-cleans

Comment: Your [first link](https://gist.github.com/marvell/7c812736565928e602c4#gistcomment-2965615) clearly explains their purpose of deleting the list files. Your [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990329/dockerfile-benefits-of-repeated-apt-cache-cleans) seems to be *exactly* the question you are asking, and it is well answered and discussed. Are you saying that you did not understand that correct answer or the discussion? Or are you hoping for some other answer?

Comment: @user535733 I found these example links _after_ I posted my question simply as an evidence to your comment of never seeing devs recommend this, a comment you have deleted. I have been following the practice of using the `rm -rf` command I posted and was simply wondering why this was recommended as I recently came across the `apt-get clean` command. I didn't have the exact links/videos I had seen previously where this was recommended which was a over a two years ago now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do different things. `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` removes package lists, loaded by  `apt update`. `apt clean` removes cached packages, loaded by `apt install` or `apt upgrade`. Both require root permissions (sudo).

Comment: Based on this explanation, there is then merit in performing both if the primary issue is to reduce a docker images size as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, better is to do both.

Answer (score 2):

The `rm` command would require sudo.  So a simple typo or hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> prematurely would irreparably destroy your system. There is absolutely no reason not to use `sudo apt clean` for this purpose.

Comment: This answer is blatantly wrong. Running `sudo apt clean` does not remove the files from `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, so the commands do not do the same thing, and using `sudo apt clean` "for this purpose" is nonsensical.

Comment: Yes @Nmath, please don't answer questions on topics you're unfamiliar with. You are mixing up package cache with package database cache and are providing wrong and misleading advice. You should remove your answer.